# Product and binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image]

So here is the question..I am stuck on part c and onwards ( probably because next bits require some tricks used in (c) ). 
Any help how to do part c and maybe the rest :D Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: For (c), keep repeating the argument you used to use part (a). 
The other parts should all follow (almost) immediately from the result in (c).

Comment: I don't quite understand what was the point of writing the product up to m then defining m in terms of k. Is it just to simplify the look of it? Should I expand it in terms of Ks or leave it as m?

Comment: Either way, they seem to use the $m$ to make the summation look a bit cleaner.